# Connecting SQL Server To Cognos Free Trial Version

Tags: sql, jdbc, cognos

I had subscribed for free trial for IBM Cognos. In that I have to connect my SQL server with it. I had tried all alternatives but none is working. According to the error, I had even given access of firewall through my system with port defined, also in sql server configuration manager. But still facing the same error when Testing the connection through ibm cognos.By default, we can only connect through jdbc.

Error

[image]

Connection In cognos

[image]

SQL Server configuration manager

[image]

Port Setting Inbound Firewall

[image]

Comment: Elaborate as to 'all alternatives'. Change localhost to the name of host of your sql server instance.

Answer (score 0):

The MSSQL database you are connecting to would not be local to the on demand server, so a host of localhost is likely not correct.

If the MSSQL is not publicly accessible you will need to use a secure gateway connection. https://www.ibm.com/docs/kk/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=demand-secure-gateway-only

Additionally, public or private you will also need to add the following to the JDBC connection URL TrustServerCertificate=true